# Finding the summation of n choose r

Tags: summation, combinations, binomial-theorem

I am just trying to understand how to find the summation of a basic combination, in order to do the ones on my assignment, and would be grateful if someone could take me step by step on how to get the summation of:
$$
\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} 
$$
I believe that the Binomial Theorem should be used, but I am unsure of how/ what to do?

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you all so much for the quick reply and help! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From binomial theorem
$$(1+t)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}t^{k}$$
for $t=1$ we get that
$$(1+1)^n=2^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}$$

Comment: $\ddot\smile{+}$

Answer (score 3):

you should use the Binomial Theorem with $x=y=1$.

you get:

$$(x+y)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}x^n y^{n-k} \Rightarrow (1+1)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}1^n 1^{n-k} \Rightarrow 2^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} $$

Comment: shouldnt the formula here be $$(x+y)^n = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}x^k y^{n-k}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$ (x + y)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n{n \choose k}x^{n - k}y^k ~ \rightarrow ~ (1 + y)^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}y^{k} ~ \rightarrow ~ 2^n = \sum_{k = 0}^n{n \choose k} $$

Answer (score 1):

Alternative by induction:

Define $\binom{n}{k}:=0$ if $k\notin\left\{ 0,\ldots,n\right\} $
and $s_{n}=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\binom{n}{k}$. 
Then $s_{0}=1$ and
$s_{n+1}=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\binom{n+1}{k}=\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n}{k}=2s_{n}$.

This makes it easy to prove by induction that $s_{n}=2^{n}$.